# Flask api endpoint only passes first arguement

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm using `curl` on the endpoint

`http://0.0.0.0:5001/event/email/?event_type=open&email_type=questions`

The result that I am getting is

```
{
    "email_type": null,
    "event_type": "open"
}
```

Why am I getting `null` for `email_type`? I suspect it has something to do with how the `&` is being dealt with by Flask?

Part of my code is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class EmailOpen(Resource):

    def get(self):
        email_type = request.args.get("email_type")
        event_type = request.args.get("event_type")

        ad_id = request.args.get("ad_id")
        # print(event_type,email_type)
        if not ad_id:
            return {"event_type":event_type,"email_type":email_type}
        return {"event_type":event_type,"email_type":email_type,"ad_id":ad_id}

api.add_resource(EmailOpen, '/event/email/')
```

I've looked up people with similar problems but they don't seem to match my scenario exactly

1. [Flask URL routing : url_for only passes first argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761925/flask-url-routing-url-for-only-passes-first-argument)
2. [Get the data received in a Flask request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request)

Comment: Have you tried default values for args? For example `request.args.get("email_type", "")`

Answer (score 1):

Bash must be interpreting things differently, adding the `""` works.

`curl "http://0.0.0.0:5001/event/email/?event_type=open&email_type=questions"`